# How do I create class diagrams from Use Cases?

Tags: uml, system, class-diagram, use-case, ooad

I am coming from the Embedded Systems domain with more than 3 years experience.
In my current project, at the beginning, I was only responsible for only software development and the Team consisted of 3 people.
But, as time passes, hardware eng. and project lead eng. left the job respectively. So far, the project moved with a zero- architecture documentation to give an output as fast as possible. Later, new project lead took over the project and started from the begining with applying V-model. We started to create product specs->HLR->DLR on EXCEL. But now, He left the job too :). Now, I am alone on my way with nearly 700 pieces of well written product requirements. Anyway, I started to gathering and classfying requirements as non-functional, functional, business, stakeholder etc. As gathering non-functionals, I also classified them scalability, performance, regulatory, design contrains etc. So far, I did not draw any use-case. Please verify me here, what I know is that input of use-case are functional requirements. So, I created a use-case cards and now I am planning to write use-case cards for each functional requirements then also write a sequence diagram for each use-case card. Now till here, am I going right ? Does notations used in use-case such as include, extend etc. help me to create class diagram ? Is this also right way ?

Comment: use cases define what to do, what the system has to do on external stimulus, while classes are part of the implementation, so your title is like "how to implement from requirements" , and *Does notations used in use-case such as include, extend etc. help me to create class diagram* is like "does to know what to do help me to do the implementation" ... probably you know the answer and know this is named programming

Comment: 1000 requirements is a lot, and you said they are well written, It seems you are not familiar with UML,  are you sure to translate them in use cases will help you to implement later ? you take the risk to be lost in huge number of use cases and just lost time without plus value.

Comment: @bruno Firstly, current number is nearly 700 including product spec and HLR derivating from product specs and DLR derivating from HLR. This is automotive grade project and 700 seems ok to me. Secondly, yes the first time I am using UML, but I think diagrams have to derivate each other while going to the implementing stage. So, there should be some inputs for class diagrams while implementing class diagram of the system. Otherwise, everything is designed in my mind. I don't want to this.

Comment: @bruno For example, while working with ex- Lead, I designed the system behavior with state-machine by my mind. There are no documented requirements, everything was on our minds. Input was our minds :) Now, I want to design a class and activity diagram with proper input, not minds :). So, creating class from 700 requirements by analyzing one by one seems not logical. Use-Case seems like a better start point to me. But due to the less experience I have and there is no one who can advise to me, I need to verify my way somehow.

Comment: but you said you already have *written* requirements, so that time they are not only in your mind. Use cases are just a way to model requirements, there are not "magic", and in same way each requirement must not be analyzed one by one (e.g. separately) the use cases must not be too. You will not have an association 1 use case -> 1 class. Programming is a more complex task

Comment: @bruno Of course, 1 use case-> 1 class is not make sense. I only focused 20-30 pieces of functional requirements to convert them use case and as converting use case cards, I am also planning to write interaction flow table (this will also help while creating test documantary in the future) for each specific use case and speficy their non-functional constraints like regulatory, performans criteria etc. if needed. Then, I will put them all together into a one system use case block and analyze them to convert class diagram. What about you this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Can classes be derived from use-cases?

When Ivar Jacobson invented use-cases he aimed at a development method that would be driven by the use-cases and allow to methodically derive the implementation from the use cases. That was his vision end of the 80s. His first attempt was called Objectory, which was bought by a larger company and lead to Rational Unified Process, which was generalized to be less proprietary into the [Unified Software Development Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process) (Unified Process, or UP in short).

There is in particular one practice that allows to translate a use-case into classes: the **[Entity Control Boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary)** approach: use-cases become `«control»` classes,  links between use-cases and actors become `«boundary»` classes, and `«entity»` classes are created for the business objects identified in (or derived from) the use-case narratives.

Once these first candidate classes are modelled, further work is undertaken during the design and classes may get reorganized to best fit into the solution (e.g. several boundary classes are regrouped for designing the GUI, and may thereafter be decomposed into UI elements, etc...).

### But is this the best approach in your case?

UP is iterative and incremental, and fits well into modern version of the [V-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model), since the early iterations of the elaboration phase aim to stabilize the architecture and teh components (or sub-systems).

However, this may be a very time-consuming approach, especially considering the huge number of use-cases that you have. If you look at all the questions that modelling a use-case usually raises, especially if you add `«include»` and `«extend»`, you risk to spend a lot of time (more than 300 days?) to draw robust use-case diagrams.  And then, using ECB, your requirements might be outdated before you finish the design!

### Alternatives

On the other side, [some non-academic authors](https://www.se-radio.net/2020/04/episode-407-juval-lowy-on-righting-software/) claim that every system has 3 to 5 really main use-cases:  as a user I don't have 700 goals for using a system. So you'd better identify these and see how they relate.  It's probable that many of the other requirements are far too detailed and could easily be assigned as additional information for the main use-cases.

In a similar thought, Ivar Jacobson has adapted his method to the current software engineering reality, with the [use-case 2.0](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook) approach.  Don't misunderstand me, the UML would still be the same, but ECB no longer appears (modern frameworks influence much more the design of the boundaries than the use-case model, and entities are modelled using more focused approaches, such as DDD).

The idea behind use-case 2.0 is to slice the main use-cases into several smaller parts and start to develop something that makes sense for the user and can then be further refined.

Comment: Entitiy, Boundary, Control technique seems best.